# How to redirect from one domain to another in haproxy

Tags: redirect, haproxy

We have setup LB using haproxy for two domain.

How to use haproxy `redirect` or `http-request redirect` to redirect one domain to another which cotain sub domain.

For example:

```
aaa.one.ccc.com  -> aaa.two.ccc.com
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an oneline solution in haproxy.cfg.
301 redirection from **aaa.one.ccc.com**  -> **aaa.two.ccc.com**

```
http-request redirect prefix http://aaa.two.ccc.com code 301 if { hdr_dom(host) -i aaa.one.ccc.com }
```

Note, this can't be in `defaults` section, only in `frontend`, `backend` or `listen`.

Answer (score 0):

Below config worked for me for both domain redirection and tcp traffic redirection from one domain-name/IP to another domain perfectly.

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1   local1
  maxconn 4096
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:EECDH+AESGCM:EECDH+CHACHA20
  ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11

defaults
  mode http
  maxconn 2048


frontend test-plane
  bind *:80
#  bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/test.pem
#  # 16000000 seconds is a bit more than 6 months
  http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16000000; includeSubDomains; preload;"

  acl demoredirect hdr_dom(host) -i dev.test.bi
  acl demoredirect hdr_dom(host) -i www.dev.test.bi
  http-request redirect location https://developer.test.bi/ code 301 if demoredirect

  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  mode http
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 5s
  timeout server 5s
#  default_backend test-plane

#backend test-plane
#  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
#  server developer.test.bi developer.test.bi:443  check inter 5s rise 2 fall 3
#  compression algo gzip
#  compression type text/css text/html text/javascript application/javascript text/plain text/xml application/json

frontend aqmp_5671
#  bind *:5671 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/test.pem
  bind *:5671
  mode tcp
  timeout client  3h
  timeout server  3h
  default_backend aqmp_5671

backend aqmp_5671
  mode tcp
  server developer.test.bi developer.test.bi:5671  check inter 5s rise 2 fall 3


frontend testserver_4389
  bind *:4389
  mode tcp
  timeout client  3h
  timeout server  3h
  default_backend testserver_4389

backend testserver_4389
  mode tcp
  server developer.test.bi developer.test.bi:4389  check inter 5s rise 2 fall 3
```